# Eye socket help

Tags: modeling

I am a noob at blender and currently I am trying to learn how to make characters, and when people on tutorials online make eyes they never show how to make the sockets. what tool is used when making the eyelids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eye lids are sort of a preference thing, there isn't exactly a tool for modeling it, but here is a simple easy way to make simple eye sockets with eyelids.

1# Assuming you're box modeling the head and you have the other side mirrored, take the one vertex in the middle of the place you want your eye to be.
[image]

2# Take that vertex and bevel it by pressing `Shift+Ctrl+B` on your keyboard, and you should see something like this. It will look like a rotated box but dont worry we'll fix that later.[image]

3# Now your going to add some edges to the mesh to help the shape of the nose and eye by hitting `K` on your keyboard. It will bring up a knife tool to cut edges into your mesh. Add the displayed edges to the mesh by just clicking in the lines.
[image]

[image]

4# After you have finished this process you will then want to model the shape of your eye by moving the vertices to your liking, make sure you are following a reference image of the human face and muscles, that can be very helpful as well. After you are done with shaping your eye, you will select the face in the middle of the eye and inset the eye once to create the eyelid by pressing `I` on your keyboard.
[image]

[image]

5# Now with that face still selected you will now extrude (`E` on your keyboard) it into the eye once to make the first half of the socket.
[image]

6# Once you've done that your will then extrude again `E` and then delete the cap face that you already have selected.
[image]

7# Now last and not least reveal your eyes and model your eye sockets once again to make them fit around your eyeballs, I added a additional loop cut around the eye socket to make it a little more easier to model with.[image]

With this particular setup it is easy to make eye shape keys for animation because all you have to do is add a new base shape key and then another shape key  for the eyes, then selecting the first inside loop of faces in the eye sockets you scale them down on the Z axes you will have closed eyes.[image]

Hope this helped you in some way.

Comment: Your welcome, it took me a while to make my own character too, I went through at least ten different characters all done in different ways to finally get what I wanted. So I recommend that you take it slow and learn some of the different ways to do it and look at a lot of reference. ☺

Comment: @McCoy If the answer truly helped you don't thank in the comments, upvote it instead, and if it really solved your problem, then consider marking it as accepted.